# Remote call in Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, bash

I am currently working on an Oracle database that will use external bash scripts. For now, what I tried to do is to place simple bash script on a local server (the same as the database) and call with a java script.

Everything works fine for now.

But, as I said, I would like subsequently the database to call scripts that are not located on the same server as the database, and thus make "remote calls". Unfortunately I do not know at all how to do so and told myself that you would be able to give me a hand !

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure that you want your database to be calling external scripts? Sounds like an enormous security hole just waiting to happen.

If you really must, you could always try calling these scripts via a remote ssh invocation. But in all honestly, it might be worth re-evaluating your global design.